# How to auto format a phone number with an associated hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know if this is possible, as its a bit of an edge case, but it would be amazing if this can be accomplished.

I have a spreadsheet of contact information, with fax numbers. At work, we send faxes via email by sending it to [faxnumber]@FaxAdmin.

What I would like to accomplish is two-part.

If I type in a 10 digit number (ex:1112223333) in A1, the following would occur:

1. It would auto-format the contents into: 111-222-3333.
   This is fairly easy to accomplish already, I believe. The next part is where Im stuck
2. It would then format 111-222-3333 as a hyperlink in the following format: 
   "mailto:1112223333@FaxAdmin","111-222-3333"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible and there are several ways to achieve this. This answer will focus on using built-in features.

## Explanation

This answer assumes that is possible to have one column for data entry and another column to hold the hyperlinks. The data entry column could be shown/hidden according to fit sheet the needs of the different uses.

### Regarding #1,

Click on Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format, write the following in the box

```
###-###-####
```

then click on the Apply button.

### Regarding #2,

#### Simple formula

Add the following formula to B1

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&A1&"@FaxAdmin",TEXT(A1,"###-###-####"))
```

then fill down as necessary.

#### Advanced formula

To automatically fill a column with hyperlinks created with data from column A, use the following formula:

```
=FILTER(
    ArrayFormula(
        HYPERLINK("mailto:"&A:A&"@FaxAdmin",TEXT(A:A,"###-###-####"))),
    LEN(A:A)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for there reply. Perhaps Im a bit daft, but Im confused about step 2 (Im still learning how to use spreadsheets). Could you walk me through what exactly I need to do? I would like to apply that formula to all of Column A, so that any numbers I enter into it get altered in that way.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clearer.